# Migrate multi-site error

Tags: php, wordpress

I have migrated a WordPress multi-site to a subdomain.
WordPress verion is 3.1 and PHP version in 5.4.

I am getting this warning: "Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /**/**/public_html/wp-includes/ms-load.php on line 139"

Any one can help in this.

Thank you,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Warning: Creating default object from empty value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245776/error-warning-creating-default-object-from-empty-value)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, shared hosts always have display_errors on. To turn this off yourself, you can attempt to modify your WordPress config.

1.Connect to your server via FTP

2.Download a copy of the  wp-config.php and open it in a text or HTML editor
Find the following section and ensure WP_DEBUG is false:

/**
* For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
*
* Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
* It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
* in their development environments.
*/

define('WP_DEBUG', false);

4.Paste the following line right below the WP_DEBUG line:
ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );

5.Save and re-upload the file to your root directory or wherever WordPress is installed.

If this does not work, you will need to contact your host about disabling PHP debugging/error display for your site.