# how fix an error Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, class, oop, object

I've a script with variables in a class ($slug).

When I run this script, it works, but I get a warning:  Warning: Creating default object from empty value.
I know, I can hide this warnings in my php.ini, but how can ik fix this warning?

```
    $test = new myclass();
class myclass {
    private $order;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->order = (object) NULL;
    }
    public function setVars($slug, $number) {
        $this -> order -> $slug -> number = $number;
    }

    public function getVars($slug) {
        echo $this -> order -> $slug -> number;
    }
}
$test -> setVars($slug="hello", $number=5);
$test -> getVars($slug="hello");
```

Comment: 1) You are instanciating the object before the class definition. 2) Modify your method default value to: function setVars($slug, $number=5);

Comment: @rogeriolino, sorry: this doens't fix my problem...

Answer (score 0):

Simply define order object as `stdClass`

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->order = new stdClass();
}
```

see this: [Creating default object from empty value in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900701/creating-default-object-from-empty-value-in-php)

also this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: sorry: this doens't fix my problem...
new stdClass() == (object)NULL

Comment: try this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323993/php-5-4-disable-warning-creating-default-object-from-empty-value